# JSONObject return with "map" type and JSONArray return with "myArrayList" type

Tags: java, arrays, json, arr

So I converted object to json using JSONObject and also created json array using JSON array, the result is good but returned with an extra type in front which is "map" for JSONObject and "myArrayList" for JSONArray.

```
"example": {
  "map": {
    "newCreditingAccountBalance": 1.0,
    "oldCreditingAccountName": "string",
    "newDebitingAccountName": "string",
    "newAutoDebitAmount": 1.0,
    "oldTenure": 1,
    "oldCreditingAccountNumber": "string",
  }
```

this is my Array Json

```
"productList": {
      "myArrayList": [
        0,
        0,
        "string",
        "string",
        0.0,
        "string",
        "string",
        "string",
        true
      ]
    }
```

this is my code for JSONObject

```
I 

    Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap();
    Map<String, Object> schema = new Gson().fromJson(
                new Gson().toJson(payload.get("schema")), new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType()
        );
   Iterator sIterator = schema.entrySet().iterator();


    while (sIterator.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry element = (Map.Entry)sIterator.next();

        Map<String, Object> values = new Gson().fromJson(
                new Gson().toJson(schema.get(element.getKey())), new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType()
        );

        if (values.containsKey("type")){
            if (values.get("type").equals("string")) {
                json.put(element.getKey().toString(), "string");
            }
            else if (values.get("type").equals("number")){
                json.put(element.getKey().toString(), 1.0);
            }
            else if (values.get("type").equals("integer")){
                json.put(element.getKey().toString(), 1);
            }
            else if (values.get("type").equals("boolean")){
                json.put(element.getKey().toString(), true);


return new JSONObject(json)
```

this is my code for JsonArray:

```
Map<String, Object> arrayschema = new Gson().fromJson(
                        new Gson().toJson(arrays.get("schema")), new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType()
                );

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                arrayschema.keySet().forEach(it -> {
                    if (arrayschema.get(it).toString().contains("type=string")) jsonArray.put("string");
                    else if (arrayschema.get(it).toString().contains("type=integer")) jsonArray.put(0);
                    else if (arrayschema.get(it).toString().contains("type=number")) jsonArray.put(0.0);
                    else if (arrayschema.get(it).toString().contains("type=boolean")) jsonArray.put(true);
                });
```

how to remove the "map" and "myArrayList"?

Comment: I'm facing something similar too, did you ever manage to get to fix this? do let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `toMap()` and `toList()`.

This solution is for `org.json.JSONObject` and `org.json.JSONArray` specifically.

Example

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject()
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put("a");
array.put("b");
array.put("c");
object.put("list", array);
```

object now equal

```
{"map": {"list": {"myArrayList": ["a", "b", "c"]}}}
```

`object.toMap()` equals

```
{"list": ["a", "b", "c"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working way too hard. I would suggest using the Json-Jackson library but Gson should have similar functionality. with Jackson if you use `ObjectMapper` class you have the method `writeValueAsString` for converting any class to JSON string and the method `readValue` for parsing it into a class instance (deserializing). Here is [ObjectMapper Javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).
But if you want an even simpler solution, I wrote my own thin wrapper over Jackson Json that allows you to serialize an object to JSON or deserialize it from Json to Object. For your case the code could be as simple as this

```
Map<String, Object> map = ... //here is your map that you got from your source
String jsonString;

    try {
      jsonString = JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString(map);
    }catch(IOException ioe) {
      //Handle exception
    }
```

In the example above map is used , but the same would work for List (or any serializable class instance)
Here is the [Javadoc for JsonUtils class](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). It is part of MgntUtils open source library written and maintained by me. You can get the library as maven artifact [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from Github, including source code and Javadoc [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)